# Repeat generation of macro

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

I would like to generate the following preprocessor pragmas

```
#pragma blabla column("0030")
#pragma blabla column("0130")
#pragma blabla column("0230")
...
#pragma blabla column("2330")
```

the hour changing from 0 to 23

Is that possible with `BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS`/`ITERATE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/comparison/greater.hpp>

#define blabla(z, n, data)                          \
    _Pragma(BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(                     \
        blabla column(                              \
            BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(                     \
                BOOST_PP_CAT(                       \
                    BOOST_PP_CAT(                   \
                        BOOST_PP_IF(                \
                            BOOST_PP_GREATER(n, 9), \
                            ,                       \
                            0                       \
                        ),                          \
                        n                           \
                    ),                              \
                    30                              \
                )                                   \
            )                                       \
        )                                           \
    ))

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(24, blabla, ~)
```

`_Pragma` saved us there because there is no way to generate preprocessor directives such as `#pragma`, however it is *very* picky about what it accepts. In particular, it doesn't do string concatenation, so `_Pragma("some" "thing")`  does not work, we have to concatenate everything in token-land *then* stringize as the last step.

Comment: Where does `_Pragma` come from? Is it portable?

Comment: @sehe it's there [since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/impl), precisely to solve the very issue of generating pragmas from/inside macros.

Comment: will c++20 have any impact on this?  on Boost.PP in general?

Comment: @MMM I don't really know, I haven't seen many preprocessor-oriented features in C++20 though.